# Deleted client forcefully and folder still exists in depot

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I have deleted client from perforce forcefully but it was not deleted from drop.

Can someone help on this ?

Comment: What does "deleted from drop" mean?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `p4 delete` command to delete files at the head revision, e.g.:

```
p4 delete //depot/folder/...
p4 submit
```

Use the `p4 obliterate` command to wipe all revisions from the repository permanently (this can't be undone and requires Perforce admin privileges):

```
p4 obliterate -y //depot/folder/...
```

Deleting a client spec has absolutely nothing to do with any existing depot files.